# Folium map doesn't work, only when using EPSG4326 crs

Tags: python, maps, gis, folium

I'm trying to create a Folium map using

`folium.Map(location=[xx, xx], crs='xxx')`

It seems like I need EPSG4326 crs.

However, this seems to be the only crs that's not working. If I specify crs='EPSG3857' or crs='EPSG3395', that's working fine, I can see a map as expected. But if I try crs='EPSG4326', the map is just grey, the same result as when I enter some crs that doesn't exist.
What could be the problem here? According to the Folium documentation, that crs should work.

I tried to use crs='EPSG3857', crs='EPSG3857' or crs='EPSG3395' and crs='EPSG4326'. The latter showed a grey background, while I was expecting a map.

Comment: Did you try with 0.0, 0.0 as location? (just as a test)? Maybe you are using the wrong "units" or you inverted x/y lat/long (note: there are different conventions, some libraries uses long/lat)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks! The coordinates system is indeed a lot different than what I expected, London should be around (0,51), but neither that nor (51,0) are even in the vicinity of Europe... But I get a visible map, so thanks for solving that.